# Implementing Action Bar in list view

Tags: android, android-listview, android-actionbar-compat, android-actionbaractivity

I want to implement an ActionBar in a listview. 
As given in developer.android.com I tried using extends ActionBar activity in my code.
My code runs fine when I give extends Activity, But I won't get an ActionBar.
The code crashes when I use extends ActionBarActivity with java.lang.exceptionininitializererror.

I have imported support library. The screenshot is attached.
The imported libraries are android-support-v4.jar
android-support-v7-appcompat.jar.

Below is my code. 
Please guide me on this.

Also please let me know if I can do it using any other way.

```
public class ImageTextListViewActivity extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

public static final String[] titles = new String[] { "Football",
        "Basketball" };

public static final Integer[] images = { R.drawable.football,
        R.drawable.basketball };

ListView listView;
List<RowItem> rowItems;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
   // actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    //android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable.setColor(0xff9ACC00);
    //actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(colorDrawable);
    //actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);

    rowItems = new ArrayList<RowItem>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
        RowItem item = new RowItem(images[i], titles[i]);
        rowItems.add(item);
    }

    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    CustomListViewAdapter adapter = new CustomListViewAdapter(this,
            R.layout.list_item, rowItems);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
        long id) {

    //Navigation to next page

    Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Football.class);
    myIntent.putExtra("Game",listView.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());
    startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);

 //Navigation ends

}
}
```

Comment: what is your minsdk version in manifest

Comment: It is 8.<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8"
              android:targetSdkVersion="11" />

Comment: your activity must extend `ActionBarActivity`

Comment: When I extend ActionBar activity it throws an error  java.lang.exceptionininitializererror. 

The code crashes and the application stops.

Comment: how have you referenced the library app compact

Comment: Using the import statement
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

Comment: have you referenced the library in your android project. i am not asking about import statement

Comment: Oh sorry!!!
I imported the .jar files of both the support libraries by using 
Build Path--> Add external Archives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add *appcompat* library as a library project not just import the jar.

Import *appcompat* into your IDE from `android_sdk_dir/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat`.

Add it to your project as a library project. (Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library -> Add.. and select appcompat).

Don't forget to change the application theme to `Theme.AppCompat`.

Comment: OOPS... Sorry, I forgot to mention that. Have added it as a library project in JAVA build path.

Comment: You can't add it from java build path. Remove it and add it as I explained in my answer